# Difference between canvas and SVG (fill effect)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, canvas

I have a basic question about canvas and SVG. I want to create an overlay with holes and fill it with some color.
It seems to work using canvas, but I want to try SVG (to handle event e.g. resize).
[image: canvas]

```
canvas.width  = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//fill background
context.globalAlpha = 0.8;
context.fillStyle = "blue"
context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);


context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
context.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gpx21/195ygzhq/

but SVG mask looks too light.

[image: svg]

```
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 19000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
">
    <defs>
        <mask id="mask1" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 0.8; fill:blue;"></rect>
            <path d="M50 50 H100 V100 H50Z" id="hole"></path>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width="200" height="200" style="fill:blue; mix-blend-mode: darken;mask:url(#mask1);"></rect>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gpx21/1fktpnr5/

how can I archieve the same effect as in canvas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of an SVG mask as a grayscale image. Where that image is white, the masked element is visible, and where it is black, the masked element is transparent.

So, to have a translucent blue `<rect>`, you can apply a `<mask>` that is mostly light gray (i.e. "almost white") except for a black part which will result in a transparent hole:

```
<defs>
    <mask id="mask1" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="lightgray"></rect>
        <path d="M50 50 H100 V100 H50Z" id="hole" fill="black"></path>
    </mask>
</defs>
<rect width="200" height="200" style="fill:blue; mask:url('#mask1');"></rect>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1fktpnr5/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple fix. When you define masks in your svg documents, mask elements can be given a fill of black to hide them, a fill of white to display them, or something in between for varying levels of transparency. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask))

In your mask code:

```
<defs>
  <mask id="mask1" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 0.8; fill:blue;"></rect>
    <path d="M50 50 H100 V100 H50Z" id="hole"></path>
  </mask>
</defs>
```

You can change your `fill:blue` to `fill:white` and this should fix it.